# How to set custom port number on swagger-api?

Tags: express, swagger

I created the project using the following command and chose Express framework.

```
swagger project create api-name
```

project starts on http://localhost:10010/

But I set my custom port number 10020.

```
Starting: /home/rajan/Documents/cse-4-1/web-lab/api/BankApi/app.js...
  project started here: http://localhost:10010/
  project will restart on changes.
  to restart at any time, enter `rs`
try this:
curl http://127.0.0.1:10020/hello?name=Scott
```

My question is why second and last line showing different port number?

My app.js file:

```
'use strict';

var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing

var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};

SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  // install middleware
  swaggerExpress.register(app);

  //var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;
  var port = 10020;
  app.listen(port);

  if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/hello']) {
    console.log('try this:\ncurl http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/hello?name=Scott');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also set the port number on yaml file. Then fixed it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, it seems express is never passed the port set in the swagger.yaml and instead just looks for an environmental var or defaults to 10010. Easy to set an env var, but a little sloppy that it doesn't look at `host`